# device rotation and loaders callback

Tags: android, loader

I have a simple question regarding the rotation of the device inside a Fragment.
I have the following loader callback with the method bindView(data) in it.

```
@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        if(data!=null && !data.moveToFirst() ) return;
        bindView(data);
    }
```

This is the bindView method.

```
public void bindView(Cursor cursor) {
String roa=cursor.isNull(COL_RETURN_ON_ASSETS)? getString(R.string.na):Utilities.localizePercentValue(getActivity,cursor.getFloat(COL_RETURN_ON_ASSETS));
     //multiple instructions with almost the same code
     ...
}
```

I pass the context(getContext()) to the method Utilities.localizePercentValue(). I don't know whether  I shoud use getActivity() or getContext() to prevent null pointer exception if I rotate the device and the method bindView hasn't finished.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you gotten a NullPointerException using this code?

Comment: yes, sometimes when i rotate at the begining the device. Sorry, with getActivity() instead of getContext().

Comment: Interesting.  If you put `if (getContext() == null) return;` then I think the `onLoadFinished()` is supposed to get called again after the rotation.  Next time you get the exception, please post the stack trace.

Comment: what should I use getContext() or getActivity() when passing the Context to a Utility method outside the fragment?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the Utilities code.  My choice would be to use the Activity and also check it for null first.  Also, I use `Activity.isFinishing()` to find out if a rotation was started.